# mysql trigger calculating age by using DOB field and autostore category based on calculated age to Database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, triggers

This is the Case...

These are some of the database structure.

- name
- dob
- category

The category field will be auto supplied (children, adult, young) base on the calculated age of course basing on the supplied DOB.

I am using `Mysql`.

CREATE TRIGGER ins_data BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

```
--calculate first age form DOB--
--based on the calulated result--
--my category field will be as (children, young or adult)--
--insert data into the database--
END;//
```

Comment: You don't store the age if you already have the DoB. DRY.

Comment: i mean not to store age but to store the options such as (children, young and adult) as referred to the calculated age based on the form entry of DOB.

0-9 children
9-15 young
15-above Adult

Example. name -> Reagan Saj
                DOB -> 11/23/1985
                Category -> ? 

based on the DOB input 11/23/1985 ....the answer(calculated age) will be the basis of the category.

Comment: rephrased title ----- 'mysql trigger calculating age by using DOB field and autostore category based on calculated age to Database'

i mean not to store age but to store the options such as (children, young and adult) as referred to the calculated age based on the form entry of DOB. 

0-9 children
9-15 young
15-above Adult

Example. name -> Reagan Saj
                DOB -> 11/23/1985
                Category -> ? 

based on the DOB input 11/23/1985 ....the answer(calculated age) will be the basis of the category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I tried to explain in my comment, you do not want to store something like this in your database. As soon as you do, it becomes a maintenance headache and is almost instantly out of date.  For example: a 9-year-old is entered into the DB. Next week is his birthday. He is now 10, yet the database still has an entry of `child (0-9)` for him. Bad design.

Instead you select what you want correctly:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) AS age,
CASE 
     WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) < 10 then "child" 
     WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) > 14 then "adult"
     ELSE "young"
END as category
FROM table_name;
```

Here is a sqlfiddle of it in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbc860/1

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql like this,

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) AS age FROM table_name;
```

In php

```
<?php
    $cur= date('Y');
    $dob = date('Y',strtotime("database value here"));
    echo $cur - $dob;
?>
```

And no need to store age in database.(already suggested by `Digital Chris`)

Comment: maybe this code will help .... 

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) AS age FROM table_name; 

inside the trigger

Comment: Thanks for the php code. Please say something on the code on Digi Cris Answer. Is it ok?